# Why does javascript ssh2 get stuck in infinite loop when using shell

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to get my application to execute a sudo command on another system by utilizing the ssh2 npm package. I have the end result working, but for some reason the code is getting stuck in an infinite loop. I don't understand how this is possible as I thought that closing the connection with conn.end would prevent this from happening. Can anyone help shed some light on why I am getting stuck in an infinite loop here?

Primary Code being executed:

```
function sshRunSudoCommand(user, pass, lanIP, command) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var Connection  = require('ssh2');
    var pwSent      = false;
    var sudosu      = false;
    var password    = pass;
    var conn        = new Connection();

    conn.on('ready', function() {
      console.log('Sudo Connection :: ready');
      conn.shell( function(err, stream) {
        if (err) throw err;
        stream
          .on('close', function() {
          console.log('Sudo Stream :: close');
          conn.end();
          resolve();
        })
          .on('data', function(data) {
          //handle sudo password prompt
          stream.write(password + '\n');
          stream.write(command + '\n');
          console.log('Sudo STDOUT: ' + data);
          resolve(data);
        })
          .on('exit', function(code, signal) {
          let exitCode = 'Stream :: exit :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal;
          conn.end();
          resolve(exitCode);
        })
          .on('end', function() {
            conn.end();
            resolve('end');
          })
          .stderr.on('data', function(data) {
          console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
          conn.end();
          resolve(data);
        });

      });
    })
      .on('keyboard-interactive',
        function(name, instructions, instructionsLang, prompts, finish) {
          // Pass answers to `prompts` to `finish()`. Typically `prompts.length === 1`
          // with `prompts[0] === "Password: "`
          console.log('pass before finish is ', pass);
          finish([pass]);
        }).on('ready', function() {
    }).connect({
      host: lanIP,
      port: 22,
      username: user,
      password: pass,
      readyTimeout: 99999,
      tryKeyboard: true // this attempts keyboard-interactive auth
    });
  };
}
```

Result: (Repeated over and over forever)

```
Sudo STDOUT: activedash:~ activeadmin$ s
Sudo STDOUT: udo 
Sudo STDOUT: profiles -I -
Sudo STDOUT: F /Users/S
Sudo STDOUT: hared/Sym
Sudo STDOUT: ply/activ
Sudo STDOUT: e-uuid.
onfigpr
Sudo STDOUT: ofile

Sudo STDOUT: active
sudo profiles -I -F /Users/Shared/Symply/active-uuid.configprofile
active
sudo profiles -I -F /Users/Shared/Symply/active-uuid.configprofile
active
sudo profiles -I -F /Users/Shared/Symply/active-uuid.configprofile
active
sudo profiles -I -F /Users/Shared/Symply/active-uuid.configprofile
active
sudo profiles
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I found was there was 2 things I needed to do to prevent the repeating action.

1. I needed to add and 'exit' command to the stream.write to tell the shell to end the session I had created with conn.shell
2. Then I could move my resolve() callback down to the .on('exit) section of code to only come back after I had run the exit command successfully.

The final code looks like this:

```
function sshRunSudoCommand(user, pass, lanIP, command) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var Connection  = require('ssh2');
    var password    = pass;
    var conn        = new Connection();

    conn.on('ready', function() {
      console.log('Sudo Connection :: ready');
      conn.shell( function(err, stream) {
        if (err) throw err;
        stream
          .on('close', function() {
          console.log('Sudo Stream :: close');
          conn.end();
          resolve();
        })
          .on('data', function(data) {
          //handle sudo password prompt
          stream.write(password + '\n');
          stream.write(command + '\n');
          stream.write('exit\n');
        })
          .on('exit', function(code, signal) {
          let exitCode = 'Stream :: exit :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal;
          conn.end();
          resolve(exitCode);
        })
          .on('end', function() {
            conn.end();
            resolve('end');
          })
          .stderr.on('data', function(data) {
          console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
          conn.end();
          resolve(data);
        });

      });
    })
      .on('keyboard-interactive',
        function(name, instructions, instructionsLang, prompts, finish) {
          // Pass answers to `prompts` to `finish()`. Typically `prompts.length === 1`
          // with `prompts[0] === "Password: "`
          console.log('pass before finish is ', pass);
          finish([pass]);
        }).on('ready', function() {
    }).connect({
      host: lanIP,
      port: 22,
      username: user,
      password: pass,
      readyTimeout: 99999,
      tryKeyboard: true // this attempts keyboard-interactive auth
    });
  };
}
```